# Is there a rule for describing the posture of different kinds of items on a table?

Tags: prepositions

It seems that a plate lays on the table, while a vase stands. I'd say utensils lay, and a pitcher stands. So the rule appears to be about whether the item is vertical or horizontal. But if the milk was left out, I'd probably say it was left sitting on the table, not standing; same for the roast. Am I wrong? If not, what's the rule?

Comment: There's an element of anthropomorphosis at play here, so you're probably better off looking at *functional* aspects, not just orientation. If it's an extended wait, people would likely be found *sitting* rather than *standing*. There isn't a 'rule', as such - use whatever term fits the picture you're painting.

Comment: Actually, it should be 'a plate _lies_ on the table'.